# GCC does not compile program

Tags: gcc, reference, libraries

I want to compile a very simple C++ program. On the first machine the compilation process works fine and also the program runs fine. However, on the second linux machine I have some libraries not found problems. The compilation process looks like this:

```
gcc -o WebPageCrawler -lawesomium-1-7 -Wall WebPageCrawler.cc
/tmp/ccoLVzvo.o: In function `main':
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `std::cout'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
...even more errors...
```

As you can see the compiler even cannot find stdlibs and the other referenced library awesomium (a headless browser) is also not available. However, the corresponding libs can all be found in `/usr/lib`. So, there must be something else wrong but I don't know what it might be.

My linux version is

```
uname -a 
Linux Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal 3.2.0-39-generic
```

I'd appriciate any help. Thx.

UPDATE:
When using g++ I get:

```
g++ -o WebPageCrawler -lawesomium-1-7 -Wall WebPageCrawler.cc
Unable to exec g++.real: No such file or directory
```

However, on the other machine I used gcc instead of g++ and it works fine there.

UPDATE2:
Okay, now I'm able to get a least the problem of the stdlibs resolved. I did this by further installing:

```
apt-get install build-essential g++
```

However, now the awesomium libs are still not found:

```
/opt/AwesomiumCrawler # g++ -v  -o WebPageCrawler -lawesomium-1-7 -Wall WebPageCrawler.cc
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++.real
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'WebPageCrawler' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE WebPageCrawler.cc -quiet -dumpbase WebPageCrawler.cc -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase WebPageCrawler -Wall -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccGGfqAI.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=98 --param ggc-min-heapsize=127439
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=98 --param ggc-min-heapsize=127439
Compiler executable checksum: 65b5171ac1bd7b3f07dbea6bdb24be3d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'WebPageCrawler' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as --64 -o /tmp/cctijQGE.o /tmp/ccGGfqAI.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'WebPageCrawler' '-Wall' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o WebPageCrawler /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. -lawesomium-1-7 /tmp/cctijQGE.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/cctijQGE.o: In function `main':
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebConfig::WebConfig()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::operator=(Awesomium::WebString const&)'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebCore::Initialize(Awesomium::WebConfig const&)'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebURL::WebURL(Awesomium::WebString const&)'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::CreateFromUTF8(char const*, unsigned int)'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::CreateFromUTF8(char const*, unsigned int)'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `Awesomium::JSValue::ToString() const'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x259): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebCore::Shutdown()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `Awesomium::JSValue::~JSValue()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebURL::~WebURL()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `Awesomium::JSValue::~JSValue()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x332): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebURL::~WebURL()'
/tmp/cctijQGE.o: In function `Update(int)':
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text+0x372): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebCore::instance()'
/tmp/cctijQGE.o: In function `Awesomium::ToString(Awesomium::WebString const&)':
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium8ToStringERKNS_9WebStringE[Awesomium::ToString(Awesomium::WebString const&)]+0x25): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::IsEmpty() const'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium8ToStringERKNS_9WebStringE[Awesomium::ToString(Awesomium::WebString const&)]+0x4d): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::ToUTF8(char*, unsigned int) const'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium8ToStringERKNS_9WebStringE[Awesomium::ToString(Awesomium::WebString const&)]+0x75): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::ToUTF8(char*, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/cctijQGE.o: In function `Awesomium::WSLit(char const*)':
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium5WSLitEPKc[Awesomium::WSLit(char const*)]+0x2d): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::CreateFromUTF8(char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/cctijQGE.o: In function `Awesomium::WebConfig::~WebConfig()':
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebStringArray::~WebStringArray()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x49): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x59): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x69): undefined reference to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()'
/tmp/cctijQGE.o:WebPageCrawler.cc:(.text._ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD2Ev[_ZN9Awesomium9WebConfigD5Ev]+0x79): more undefined references to `Awesomium::WebString::~WebString()' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As already mentioned the libs lie in

```
/usr/lib # ls -l *awe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     8032 Feb 12 18:49 awesomium_process
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       21 Feb 12 18:49 libawesomium-1-7.so -> libawesomium-1-7.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       23 Feb 12 18:49 libawesomium-1-7.so.2 -> libawesomium-1-7.so.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63475481 Feb 12 18:49 libawesomium-1-7.so.2.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command to compile C++ code is `g++`, not `gcc`.

They're both part of the same collection, but the `g++` command adds some extra options; in particular, it implicitly links the C++ standard library.

When compiling with `-c`, to generate just an object file and not invoke the linker, it may not matter -- but you're generating an executable, which means the linker needs to know about the dependency on the C++ standard library.

*UPDATE:* And now that you've updated the question: You may need to install `g++` (on your system, `apt-get install build-essential g++`).

And now you have a different problem: `g++` can't find the "awesomium" libraries. The libraries are in `/usr/lib`, so you shouldn't need to specify a `-L` option. The problem is that the `-l` option needs to *follow* the file that depends on it.

The linker processes its command-line arguments in order, keeping track of which symbols still need to be resolved and resolving any unresolved symbols in objects or libraries that it processes later.

So rather than:

```
g++ -o WebPageCrawler -lawesomium-1-7 -Wall WebPageCrawler.cc
```

try:

```
g++ -Wall WebPageCrawler.cc -lawesomium-1-7 -o WebPageCrawler
```

That *specific* order isn't mandatory, but it should work.